# Sigma algebra generated by a homeomorphic random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ be our probability space with sigma algebra of borel sets on $[0,1]$ and Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let Y be a random variable such that $Y(\omega) = Y(1-\omega)$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$.

Assume that $Y_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]}$ is a homeomorphism on $Y([0, \frac{1}{2}])$.

What does $\sigma-$algebra generated by $Y$ look like?

The information that $Y_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]}$ is a homeomorphism tells us that the image of every borel set in $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ is a borel set. Is that correct? What does that tell us about $\sigma(Y)?$

I need this in order to prove that for any random variable $X$ and for random variable $Y$ described above we have $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y)(\omega) = \frac{X(\omega) + X(1- \omega)}{2}$$

When I integrate $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ over a $\sigma(Y)-$measurable set $B$ I get $$\int_B\mathbb{E}(X|Y) dP = \frac{1}{2}\int_B X(\omega) dP(\omega) + \frac{1}{2}\int_B X(1-\omega) dP(\omega)$$

Now we know that $Y(\omega) = Y(1-\omega)$ but we do not know that about $X$. Anyway, shouldn't $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ be a measurable function of $Y$?

Comment: you should try to prove that $\sigma(Y)$ is exactly constituted the sets of the form $A \cup \tau(A)$, where $A$ is a Borel subset of $[0,1/2]$ and $\tau(\omega)=1-\omega$. (if you want to make things concrete, you could assume $Y(\omega) = |\omega-1/2|$ since the general case is completely analogous).

Comment: @pgassiat And if I do that, it will then be evident that the sum of the two integrals above gives $\int_BXdP$

Comment: @pgassiat If $Y|_{[]0,1/2}$ is a homeomorphism on its image and $Y(y)=Y(1-y)$, then $Y|_{[1/2,1]}$ is also a homeomorphism on its image. Is that correct? If our random variable $Y$ was defined on $[a,b]$ instead of $[0,1]$ would the sigma algebra be $\{A \cup a+b-A : A \in \mathcal{B}[a,b] \}?$

Comment: Let $S:\Omega\to\Omega$ be defined by $S(\omega)=1-\omega$, then you might try to prove that the sigma-algebra $\sigma(Y) $ is $\sigma(Y)=\{B\in\mathcal B([0,1])\mid S(B)=B\}$ and that a random variable $U$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable if and only if $U\circ S=U$ almost surely. Then, $Z=\frac12(X+X\circ S)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable since $S\circ S$ is the identity and, for every $B$ in $\sigma(Y)$, $E(X\circ S:B)=E(X:S(B))=E(X:B)$ hence $E(Z:B)=E(X:B)$, QED.

Comment: The previous comments already answer this. Your formula for the conditional expectation is a function of $Y$ since $Y$ is monotone on $[0,1/2]$, so $\omega$ can be obtained from $y=Y(\omega)$. It is in fact intuitively totally obvious because $\omega, 1-\omega$ are the two points where $Y=Y(\omega)$, so this is the set you need to (partially) average over.