# On computing a conditional expectation $E[Y|X]$ where $Y$ is not known.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

**Preface**:
This question is based on the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944743/compute-the-conditional-expectation-eyx-for-a-measurable-function-y-and-a) question given in the comments.

**The problem:**

> Consider the Lebesgue probability space on the interval $[0,1)$. (I.e. the state space is $Ω = [0, 1)$, the $\sigma$-field is the set of Lebesgue measurable sets and the measure is the Lebesgue measure.) We define the random variable $X$ as:
>   $$X(w)=\begin{cases} 2w &, 0\leq w < 1/2 \\ 2w−1 &, 1/2\leq w<1 \end{cases}$$
>   Compute the conditional expectation $E(Y |X)$ where $Y : [0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function.

**My question:**

Why can we write $$E(Y\mid X)(\omega)=\frac{Y(\omega)+Y(\omega+\frac12)\mathbf 1_{2\omega<1}+Y(\omega-\frac12)\mathbf 1_{2\omega\geqslant1}}2$$ ? What theorem are we appealing to?

EDIT: I think an answer was given to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276030/sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-homeomorphic-random-variable).

Comment: The title does not agree with the equation you have written Are you computing $E(X|Y)$ or $E(Y|X)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy from the linked question it is $E(Y \mid X)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I will edit, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Did  Maybe you could take a look at this question since it comes from a comment of yours. In any case thanks for all the answers and your activity on mathstack!